# How to get image zoomed automatically when focused while horizontally scrolling in android

Tags: android, image-processing, horizontal-scrolling, zooming

I am trying to implement the above scenario described in the image, There were couple of designs like oval, star, rectangle, square and many more, when I will scroll that images, the center image should be zoom when it focused and when I scroll the images, the left images needs to be zoom out and of course right one also.

I have tried so many example of carousel android but it doesn't work for me. Also tried horizontal scrollview but the result remains same. I have implemented this example from github, Check the [link](https://github.com/ninchuu/android-carousel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a demo application for you and placed it on Github.

You can download this demo from below [link](http://github.com/DeepMehtaIPath/ImageSlider-for-Android):

I think this will surely work for you and all others who want this kind of sliders in Android.

Cheers,

Comment: It's great example, Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like [Viewflow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) and set a zoom animation in the OnViewSwitchListener.
Something like:

```
viewflow.setOnViewSwitchListener(new ViewFlow.ViewSwitchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwitched(View view, int position) {
                view.animate().scaleY(1.2f).scaleX(1.2f).start();
            }
        });
```